# Regex : Validating Domain Name with Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate Domain Names using Regex.

This is my regex :

```
^((?!-)(\*\.)?[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}
```

Basically, I don't want to match string ending with "-" before "."
Ex: test.google-.com

In this case its "google-" but its getting matched and thats an issue for me.

Although, "test-.google.com" doesn't gets matched and its expected.

I am suspecting, "negative lookbehind ((?<!-))" is working only 1st time and for subsequent strings its not working.

Please let me know the way to proceed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a repeating pattern, starting the match with `[A-Za-z0-9]` so you don't need the lookahead at the start.

Then you could match an optional `-` before starting matching the `.` but only when it is not before the last occurrence until the end of the string.

**Note** that although he pattern matches the example data, this does not validate a domain name.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,63}(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,63})*(?:-(?!\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,63}$))?(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,63})+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KpPLIf/1)